# Why did American English change certain past tense verb endings from ‑t to ‑ed but not others?

Tags: etymology, transatlantic-differences, inflectional-morphology, irregular-verbs

I always get “mad” (we don’t actually get upset with each other) at a friend of mine because he uses the UK versions
for the past tense of verbs like *spill* or *spell*, saying *spilt* or
*spelt* instead of the American versions like *spilled* or *spelled*, etc. He’s “retaliated” (just teasing) by saying ✻*feeled* and ✻*builded* rather than *felt*
and *built*.

Does anyone know why American English changed *‑t* to *‑ed* only for certain
verbs but not for others?

Comment: American English? Which one? Note how many theatres (sorry, theaters) are spelled/spelt the -re way on Broadway. And in the UK, we have dogs homes and dogs' homes (the funded kennels). We are two nations divided by many streams of language.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth This question appears to be based on a false hypothesis. It's not true that you cannot use the *-t* versions of past tenses in the United States: forms like *spilt, swept, slept, dreamt, wept, kept, knelt, crept, leapt, sent, lent, rent* and all the rest continue to be grammatical in American English. That's because there are no “for-use-in-England-only” inflections of verbs in our shared language. Variant forms have always existed everywhere for these even if specific personal preferences vary. On the other hand, pronouns like *hoo* and *tha* don’t cross the pond.

Comment: It's "spelled" because "spelt" is a form of wheat.

Comment: @HotLicks Smoked smelt are a wonder to be—um, olfactorily perceived.

Comment: @tchrist - I wonder why one would get mad at someone for *misusing* the language, if they are not doing so intentionally, and their errors do not create a hardship for anyone.

Comment: @HotLicks I—um felt (also plant-related) there must be a suitable counterexample, but tchrist has won the race to the best one.

Comment: Is your friend from either the US or the UK? Is nationalism involved?

Comment: [British](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=spelled%2Cspelt&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3) versus [American](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=spelled%2Cspelt&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3).  The timing suggests Noah Webster had something to do with it.

Comment: And here in Canada we're bombarded by all possible spellings.  I've noticed that I personally tend to use "—t" as an adjective and "—ed" as a verb.  But sometimes I use "—t" as a verb if it's very weak (e.g. "*I burnt the toast by leaving it in too long*" vs. "*The buttered toast tasted rancid, so I threw it into the fire and burned it.*").

Comment: @HotLicks But the language is not being "misused", and [using *-t* forms is no error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_irregular_verbs). This is some variant on the recency illusion applied to locale instead: different isn't wrong and it is folly to demand that another native speaker change their native speech to mimic your own differences.

Comment: @tchrist - Right.  If it's silly to get mad at someone for misusing the language, it's even sillier to get mad at them for using it correctly, just not as the listener would like.

Comment: @KannE - I would probably say "It smelled to high heaven".  (Tropical southern Minnesota)

Comment: Apologies if I came off rude or snobbish. Our language discussions are a characteristic of our friendship; we don't actually get upset with each other. It just made me curious if there was a reason that some words use both -lt or -ed, but some don't.

Comment: @ElleFromm Ok thanks. I've edited your post to include that you two aren't actually angry with each other, and to apply some formatting improvements. Please feel free to edit it if I’ve misstated anything.

Comment: Understand that there are some people who LOVE to mispronounce words (especially if there's a pun involved).

Comment: It is not always as you say: Americans say **lit a candle**, Brits can say **lighted a candle**; there are other examples.

Answer (score 3):

From a linguistic and phonetics standpoint, in the majority of cases, the suffix *-t* as a formative of past participle of verbs appeared as a result of the reduction of *-ed* to *-'d*, and the devocalization of *d*.

Here is the full explanation from *OED* with some historical notes:

> Formative of the past participle in some weak verbs, for earlier *-d* and *-ed* (see -ed suffix<sup>1</sup>), due usually to the devocalization of d after a breath consonant, as in *nipped, nip'd, nipt*. In some verbs the use of *t* for *-ed* goes back to Germanic, esp. in apparently contracted or irregular verbs, as *bought, brought, might, thought, wrought* (Gothic *bauht, brâht, maht, þâht, waurht*); in others it appears in West Germanic, as *sought* (Gothic *sôkid*, Old Saxon and Old English *sôht*); in others only in Old English as *laught (læht), taught (tæht, taht)*. But in the majority of cases the *t* is of later appearance, arising from the reduction of -ed to -'d, -d in Middle or Modern English, with consequent devocalization of d, not only after breath consonants, as in *dropt, nipt, crept, slept, swept, left, lost, tost, past*, but, in certain cases, after liquids and nasals, as in *felt, spelt, spilt, dreamt, burnt, meant, pent*; also in contracted formations, such as *built, bent, lent, sent, spent, girt, cast*. But in many words where the pronunciation has *t*, the current spelling is *-ed*, e.g. *blessed, dropped, hushed, passed for blest, dropt, husht, past*.

*OED* has a separate entry for the suffix *-t* as a formative of the past tense of some weak verbs and adds that: "In modern English on the contrary the spelling in *t* is more frequent in the past participle, esp. when used adjectivally, than in the past tense: cf. *tempest-tost* (see tempest-tossed adj.), the wind *tossed* the ship; in time *past*, he *passed* his time."

Additionally, it is not only used in British English. For example, shortening of a long vowel in the participle of certain verbs, as in *crept, slept*, the spelling with *-t* is universal.

Comment: did anyone ever write *kilt* for *killed*?

Comment: @green_ideas [William F. Nolan](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?53737), for one.

Comment: @green_ideas: _Kissed_ was _kist_ in Middle English also. _OED_ has this note: "In some cases even the form in _-ed_ is a mere modern fashion of spelling, at variance with both the pronunciation and the history; thus, _kissed_ was in Old Saxon _kusta_, Old English _cyste_, Middle English _kist_, as actually pronounced; it has come to be spelt _kissed_, because in other verbs _-ed_ is pronounced _-t._"

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "shortening of a long vowel in the participle is universal": *creep, crept; keep, kept;  leap leapt; sleep, slept; weep, wept*; but *heap, heaped; peep, peeped; reap, reaped; seep, seeped; steep, steeped*.

Comment: @PeterShor: Taken along with the previous sentence, I think the point is that "slept" is not a British English spelling: Americans also always use "slept" and never use an *-ed* spelling for this word.

Comment: @PeterShor: For certain verbs, not all with a long vowel.

Comment: I am curious: is UK 'lighted' vs 'US 'lit' covered in this explanation?

Comment: @green_ideas: It is somewhat related and also explained with stress patterns and rhythmic alternation. You can read the details here: [One Language, Two Grammars?: Differences Between British and American English](https://books.google.ca/books?id=Mks2PlArmFsC&pg=PA455&dq=lighted+lit+spelling+irregular&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj8mvGS8LDmAhXJPM0KHSljAWIQ6AEIPzAD#v=onepage&q=lighted%20lit%20spelling%20irregular&f=false)

Comment: thanks so much @ermanen I shall enjoy it

Comment: hmmm, it's interesting, but the discussion focuses on the participle and I am most familiar with lit/lighted used as a verb. nevertheless, I learnt something new

Answer (score 2):

This question is very hard, so I will provide 20% of an answer only.

The British isles had speakers of many different dialects of English. The people who went on to colonize the US generally did not speak RP, but rather mostly less reputable dialects. In most cases you'll find that features of "American" English are simply features of a non-RP English dialect that disproportionately supplied American colonists. And so on for other world Englishes. I suppose some Americanisms can also be explained by substrate influences (esp. Spanish loan words), but most are explainable by an evolutionary bottleneck, as it were.

Comment: You could mine [this reference](https://www.google.com/books/edition/One_Language_Two_Grammars/Mks2PlArmFsC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=regular) for a far stronger answer.

Comment: @tchrist I had at hand Crystal's *The English Language*, was about to revise, then decided to wash the dishes instead!

Comment: Interestingly, [Samuel Johnson's 1755 dictionary](https://johnsonsdictionaryonline.com/page-view/?i=1897) shows only **spelled** (or rather, **spell'd**). I'm pretty sure that there was no such thing as "RP" in the 18th Century.

Comment: @tchrist That reference undermines jlovegren's argument. "It may well be the case that the more conservative nature of BrE with respect to this variable has to be attributed to an avoidance strategy treating the regular forms as a morphological Americanism".

Comment: @Spencer the reference is in no position to undermine my claim. It is not a work of historical linguistics and is not really a relevant resource for answering the question.

Comment: Bear in mind that English RP didn't really become established until sometime in the nineteenth century. How members of the governing class spoke in the eighteenth century is really a matter of some conjecture. Whilst historic written forms of language are readily available - there are no voice recordings from those times.